# How to use coreapi client with django rest framework?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I've integrated django rest framework version 3.10 into an existing django 2.2 project, placing api root at `/api`.

Now I'm trying to use coreapi cli client to upload some documents to the server.

```
$ coreapi get http://localhost:8000/openapi
<DownloadedFile '/root/.coreapi/downloads/openapi (4)', open 'rb'>
$ coreapi get http://localhost:8000/api
{
    "invoices": "http://localhost:8000/api/invoices/"
}
$ coreapi action invoices list
Index ['invoices']['list'] did not reference a link. Key 'invoices' was not found.
```

`/openapi` is an endpoint that generates schema upon request and returns

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  title: Orka
  version: TODO
  description: API for orka project
paths:
  /invoices/:
    get:
      operationId: ListInvoices
      parameters: []
      responses:
        '200':
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                required:
                - file_name
                - original_file_name
                properties:
                  file_name:
                    type: string
                  original_file_name:
                    type: string
                    maxLength: 80
                  upload_date:
                    type: string
                    format: date-time
                    readOnly: true
                  data:
                    type: object
                    nullable: true
                  confidence:
                    type: number
                  user_verified:
                    type: boolean
  /invoices/{id}/:
    get:
      operationId: retrieveInvoice
      parameters:
      - name: id
        in: path
        required: true
        description: A unique integer value identifying this Invoice.
        schema:
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                required:
                - file_name
                - original_file_name
                properties:
                  file_name:
                    type: string
                  original_file_name:
                    type: string
                    maxLength: 80
                  upload_date:
                    type: string
                    format: date-time
                    readOnly: true
                  data:
                    type: object
                    nullable: true
                  confidence:
                    type: number
                  user_verified:
                    type: boolean
```

Nothing complicated and path for invoices exists (even though it should be `/api/invoices`).

I've successfully got coreapi to work with external apis, so this seems to be problem with how I configure my urls and/or views.

Both of them are dead simple.

```py
# urls.py
from rest_framework import routers

from . import views


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'invoices', views.InvoiceViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]


# views.py
# ... imports ...

class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """Defines API representation of invoices"""

    class Meta:  # pylint:disable=too-few-public-methods, missing-docstring
        model = Invoice
        fields = (
            'file_name',
            'original_file_name',
            'upload_date',
            'data',
            'confidence',
            'user_verified',
        )


class InvoiceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Defines api views for invoices"""
    # default permissions are set in settings.py
    parser_classes = (JSONParser, XMLParser, FormParser, MultiPartParser)
    queryset = Invoice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InvoiceSerializer

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=True)
    def upload_with_ground_truth_file(self, request, pk):
        pass
```

It seems that I'm missing something glaringly obvious. What do I need to configure so I can use coreapi client to consume my api?

Comment: This must be because your `coreapi get http://localhost:8000/openapi` did not actually load the schema ("current document"), so your actions went against previously loaded schema. I just wonder how did your solve it, since I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: See what happens when there is no previously loaded schema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982787/coreapi-action-no-current-document

Answer (score 4):

I hit the same error -- python 3.8.5, Django 3.1, DRF 3.12.1. The similarity for me was that `coreapi` returns a `DownloadedFile` instead of a `Document`, which seems to happen when `coreapi` receives a content-type that it doesn't expect.

For me, solution was:

1. `pip install openapi-codec` (if you haven't installed it yet)
2. `coreapi get http://localhost:8000/openapi?format=openapi-json --format=openapi`

You'll know it succeeded because you won't see any mention of `DownloadedFile`, instead a summary of the available tags/actions.

Not sure why forcing the format should be necessary.

Comment: You might also have to add an Accept header for "application/vnd.oai.openapi+json" when downloading the schema and put it back to "application/json" afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for helpful answer. About forcing format you may read on doc page (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/api-clients/#codecs): "By default the command line client only includes support for reading Core JSON schemas", I think that default drf serving schema is OpenAPI-like

Comment: In my case problem was similar, but extened. I was using by default Spectacular for generating schema, to be specific `SpectacularApiView`, which serves schema in yaml, using `OpenAPI format`. Then I switched to `SpectacularJSONAPIView`. And finally I used command `coreapi get "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/schema/" --format=openapi`