# CoreAPI to OpenAPI schema generation transition (Django REST Framework)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, openapi, core-api

I'm creating an API using Django REST Framework 3.12.0. This is the latest version released on the 13th of October 2020.

The 3.10 version (September 2019) introduced **OpenAPI** based schema generation instead of CoreAPI, which has been deprecated (see release notes [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.10-announcement/)).

This change introduces regressions in schema auto-generation:

1. Redundant Operation IDs (`operators create` becomes `operators createOperator`, see example below),
2. A "workaround" is required to get schema using `coreapi` cli command (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64179122/5884000)),
3. **Mandatory parameters defined in serializer are not extracted in schema generation**, thus I cannot properly use the `coreapi` cli command.

**The last point is the real problematic one.**

I can easily switch from the OpenAPI to the (deprecated) CoreAPI AutoSchema class changing the `url` parameter in `get_schema_view` function and adding this in `settings.py`:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # [...]
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema',
}
```

## Example

Below is an example using both schema classes.

`models.py`:

```py
class Operator(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField(unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
```

`serializers.py`:

```py
class OperatorSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Operator
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'code', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

`views.py`:

```py
class OperatorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Operator.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OperatorSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

### Using Core API

```sh
# No workaround
coreapi get http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/openapi
# [...]
    operators: {
        list([page])
        create(code, first_name, last_name)
        read(id)
        update(id, code, first_name, last_name)
        partial_update(id, [code], [first_name], [last_name])
        delete(id)
    }
# [...]

# I can create an operator.
coreapi action operators create --param code=1234 --param first_name="John" --param last_name="Doe"
{
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/operators/68/",
    "id": 68,
    "code": 1234,
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe"
}
```

### Using Open API

```sh
# Needs a workaround
coreapi get http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/openapi/?format=openapi-json --format=openapi
# [...]
    operators: {
        listOperators([page])
        createOperator()
        retrieveOperator(id)
        updateOperator(id)
        partialUpdateOperator(id)
        destroyOperator(id)
    }
# [...]

# I cannot create an operator as parameter are unknown.
coreapi action operators createOperator --param code=1234 --param first_name="John" --param last_name="Doe"
Traceback (most recent call last):
# [...]
coreapi.exceptions.ParameterError: {'first_name': 'Unknown parameter.', 'code': 'Unknown parameter.', 'last_name': 'Unknown parameter.'}
```

How to have a CoreAPI-like schema generation using the new OpenAPI one?